# Cannot find module error code in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a "cannot find module" error. All the screenshots from atom are attached. i believe i am entering the correct filepaths when calling the search_bar file.

Here is a link to the google doc with all the screenshots: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yt2YrapLw04kKk5tnIxyEik6RAJbBpTpl-CSaAYZzE8/edit?usp=sharing

```
bundle.js:64 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 
"./components/search_bar"
at webpackMissingModule (bundle.js:64)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:64)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:47)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at bundle.js:40
at bundle.js:43
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
From the NPM Start process, issue was that in the search_bar file, i had written the following at the top:

import React from ('react');

The parenthesis around 'react' were screwing it up...

All working fine now...